# macbook won't go to sleep while in shared connection

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I just moved to a new place and don't have any internet connection so I use my phone to share it with my macbook (Big Sur 11.5.2).

While sharing it, I noticed that my macbook is not going to sleep anymore, even when closing the lid. I noticed it because I didn't have to enter my password after opening the lid and then by listening to music while the lid was closed...

I always disconnect the power supply before closing my macbook, but now I have to switch Wi-Fi off in order to get it to sleep.

Any idea why / How can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you please include in your question what your research turned up in terms of possible fixes? Have you for example seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29480/24324)?